# Firebase: Null check operator used on a null value on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have configured my Firebase credentials. But yet I am still getting errors. Here is what the simulator is showing me.  [image: Error screen]

Here is my code

```
await Auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailRegistered, password: passwordRegistered);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const MainNav()),
    );
```

Which then navigates to the next screen and has this line which is allegedly calling the error

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

I would appreciate any sort of answers in regards to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using null-aware operator `?.` instead of the null check operator `!`.

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
```

Also  check if the user is authenticated before accessing by:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  // do something with user
} else {
  // handle the case when the user is not authenticated
}
```